# ASP - How to export HTML table to Excel?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm working with an old classic ASP page that generates an HTML table through SQL.  Currently, after the table is generated, the user clicks on a button that redirects the user to another page and re-runs the SQL to generate a new table, but this new page's content type set to Excel format.

I would like to eliminate this overhead and instead pass an HTML table to the next page based on the table's ID.

I know that I can find the object through JavaScript's `document.getElementById('IdHere');` but how can I pass that variable through to the next page?

The following is the current form structure:

```
<form method="post" name="xlsexport" target="_blank" 
    action="payment_analysis_xls.asp?<%=Request.QueryString%>&filename=paymentAnalysis.xls">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:document.xlsexport.submit();">Export to Excel</a>&nbsp;
    <input type="image" src="xls.gif"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="report" value="analysis"/></form>
```

I assume I'll have to change the form's onClick event to a function that I create, that will grab the table by ID.  But how can I proceed from there?

Thank you!

Comment: if the data doesn't get modified between the two pages, just stuff it into a server-side session so you don't have to round-trip it through the client.

Comment: It does not get modified between the pages.  Forgive my ignorance of classic ASP, can I find the table using server side ASP if the table doesn't have `runat="server"` like ASP.NET would?

Comment: Which type of overhead are you trying to eliminate: 1. Load on your SQL server? 2. Load on your ASP web server? 3. Time for your user loading the report?

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the load on the web server and sql server, as it will only make this (semi) intensive query once, rather than twice as it's doing now.

Comment: Couldn't you just send your entire table as a hidden form field?